# Are you aware of uncomptability between hibernate-enhance-maven-plugin and spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch?

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data, spring-data-elasticsearch

i work on a spring-boot project (version 2.3.8.RELEASE) with Hibernate (version 5.4.27.Final) and elasticsearch (spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch).

I want to enable bytecode enhancement lazy loading to increase performance of my @OneToOne relationships.

I added the hibernate-enhance-maven-plugin to my configuration following this [Hibernate LazyToOne annotation](https://vladmihalcea.com/hibernate-lazytoone-annotation/) article.

But when i start my application i got the following error stacktrace :

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'partnerSearchRepository' defined in com.wenabi.website.repository.search.PartnerSearchRepository defined in @EnableElasticsearchRepositories declared on DatabaseConfiguration: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected to be able to resolve a type but got null! This usually stems from types implementing raw Map or Collection interfaces!
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1794)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:594)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:516)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:322)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1307)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1227)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:886)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:790)
... 51 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected to be able to resolve a type but got null! This usually stems from types implementing raw Map or Collection interfaces!
at org.springframework.data.util.TypeInformation.getRequiredActualType(TypeInformation.java:184)
at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.AbstractPersistentProperty.getActualType(AbstractPersistentProperty.java:286)
at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.mapping.SimpleElasticsearchPersistentProperty.initDateConverter(SimpleElasticsearchPersistentProperty.java:122)
at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.mapping.SimpleElasticsearchPersistentProperty.<init>(SimpleElasticsearchPersistentProperty.java:91)
at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.mapping.SimpleElasticsearchMappingContext.createPersistentProperty(SimpleElasticsearchMappingContext.java:53)
at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.mapping.SimpleElasticsearchMappingContext.createPersistentProperty(SimpleElasticsearchMappingContext.java:34)
at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext$PersistentPropertyCreator.createAndRegisterProperty(AbstractMappingContext.java:542)
at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext$PersistentPropertyCreator.doWith(AbstractMappingContext.java:520)
at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithFields(ReflectionUtils.java:705)
at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.addPersistentEntity(AbstractMappingContext.java:389)
at java.base/java.util.Collections$SingletonSet.forEach(Collections.java:4797)
at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext$PersistentPropertyCreator.createAndRegisterProperty(AbstractMappingContext.java:562)
at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext$PersistentPropertyCreator.doWith(AbstractMappingContext.java:520)
at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithFields(ReflectionUtils.java:705)
at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.addPersistentEntity(AbstractMappingContext.java:389)
at java.base/java.util.Collections$SingletonSet.forEach(Collections.java:4797)
at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext$PersistentPropertyCreator.createAndRegisterProperty(AbstractMappingContext.java:562)
at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext$PersistentPropertyCreator.doWith(AbstractMappingContext.java:520)
at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithFields(ReflectionUtils.java:705)
at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.addPersistentEntity(AbstractMappingContext.java:389)
at java.base/java.util.Collections$SingletonSet.forEach(Collections.java:4797)
at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext$PersistentPropertyCreator.createAndRegisterProperty(AbstractMappingContext.java:562)
at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:183)
at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:177)
at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195)
at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:177)
at java.base/java.util.HashMap$ValueSpliterator.forEachRemaining(HashMap.java:1675)
at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484)
at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:150)
at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:173)
at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:497)
at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext$PersistentPropertyCreator.addPropertiesForRemainingDescriptors(AbstractMappingContext.java:537)
at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.addPersistentEntity(AbstractMappingContext.java:390)
at java.base/java.util.Collections$SingletonSet.forEach(Collections.java:4797)
at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext$PersistentPropertyCreator.createAndRegisterProperty(AbstractMappingContext.java:562)
at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:183)
at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:177)
at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195)
at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:177)
at java.base/java.util.HashMap$ValueSpliterator.forEachRemaining(HashMap.java:1675)
at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484)
at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:150)
at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:173)
at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:497)
at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext$PersistentPropertyCreator.addPropertiesForRemainingDescriptors(AbstractMappingContext.java:537)
at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.addPersistentEntity(AbstractMappingContext.java:390)
at java.base/java.util.Collections$SingletonSet.forEach(Collections.java:4797)
at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext$PersistentPropertyCreator.createAndRegisterProperty(AbstractMappingContext.java:562)
at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext$PersistentPropertyCreator.doWith(AbstractMappingContext.java:520)
at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithFields(ReflectionUtils.java:705)
at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.addPersistentEntity(AbstractMappingContext.java:389)
at java.base/java.util.Collections$SingletonSet.forEach(Collections.java:4797)
at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext$PersistentPropertyCreator.createAndRegisterProperty(AbstractMappingContext.java:562)
at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext$PersistentPropertyCreator.doWith(AbstractMappingContext.java:520)
at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithFields(ReflectionUtils.java:705)
at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.addPersistentEntity(AbstractMappingContext.java:389)
at java.base/java.util.Collections$SingletonSet.forEach(Collections.java:4797)
at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext$PersistentPropertyCreator.createAndRegisterProperty(AbstractMappingContext.java:562)
at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:183)
at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:177)
at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195)
at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:177)
at java.base/java.util.HashMap$ValueSpliterator.forEachRemaining(HashMap.java:1675)
at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484)
at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:150)
at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:173)
at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:497)
at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext$PersistentPropertyCreator.addPropertiesForRemainingDescriptors(AbstractMappingContext.java:537)
at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.addPersistentEntity(AbstractMappingContext.java:390)
at java.base/java.util.Collections$SingletonSet.forEach(Collections.java:4797)
at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext$PersistentPropertyCreator.createAndRegisterProperty(AbstractMappingContext.java:562)
at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:183)
at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:177)
at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195)
at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:177)
at java.base/java.util.HashMap$ValueSpliterator.forEachRemaining(HashMap.java:1675)
at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484)
at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:150)
at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:173)
at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:497)
at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext$PersistentPropertyCreator.addPropertiesForRemainingDescriptors(AbstractMappingContext.java:537)
at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.addPersistentEntity(AbstractMappingContext.java:390)
at java.base/java.util.Collections$SingletonSet.forEach(Collections.java:4797)
at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext$PersistentPropertyCreator.createAndRegisterProperty(AbstractMappingContext.java:562)
at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext$PersistentPropertyCreator.doWith(AbstractMappingContext.java:520)
at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithFields(ReflectionUtils.java:705)
at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.addPersistentEntity(AbstractMappingContext.java:389)
at java.base/java.util.Collections$SingletonSet.forEach(Collections.java:4797)
at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext$PersistentPropertyCreator.createAndRegisterProperty(AbstractMappingContext.java:562)
at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:183)
at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:177)
at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195)
at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:177)
at java.base/java.util.HashMap$ValueSpliterator.forEachRemaining(HashMap.java:1675)
at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484)
at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:150)
at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:173)
at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:497)
at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext$PersistentPropertyCreator.addPropertiesForRemainingDescriptors(AbstractMappingContext.java:537)
at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.addPersistentEntity(AbstractMappingContext.java:390)
at java.base/java.util.Collections$SingletonSet.forEach(Collections.java:4797)
at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext$PersistentPropertyCreator.createAndRegisterProperty(AbstractMappingContext.java:562)
at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext$PersistentPropertyCreator.doWith(AbstractMappingContext.java:520)
at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithFields(ReflectionUtils.java:705)
at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.addPersistentEntity(AbstractMappingContext.java:389)
at java.base/java.util.Collections$SingletonSet.forEach(Collections.java:4797)
at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext$PersistentPropertyCreator.createAndRegisterProperty(AbstractMappingContext.java:562)
at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:183)
at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:177)
at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195)
at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:177)
at java.base/java.util.HashMap$ValueSpliterator.forEachRemaining(HashMap.java:1675)
at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484)
at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:150)
at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:173)
at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:497)
at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext$PersistentPropertyCreator.addPropertiesForRemainingDescriptors(AbstractMappingContext.java:537)
at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.addPersistentEntity(AbstractMappingContext.java:390)
at java.base/java.util.Collections$SingletonSet.forEach(Collections.java:4797)
at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext$PersistentPropertyCreator.createAndRegisterProperty(AbstractMappingContext.java:562)
at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext$PersistentPropertyCreator.doWith(AbstractMappingContext.java:520)
at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithFields(ReflectionUtils.java:705)
at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.addPersistentEntity(AbstractMappingContext.java:389)
at java.base/java.util.Collections$SingletonSet.forEach(Collections.java:4797)
at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext$PersistentPropertyCreator.createAndRegisterProperty(AbstractMappingContext.java:562)
at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext$PersistentPropertyCreator.doWith(AbstractMappingContext.java:520)
at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithFields(ReflectionUtils.java:705)
at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.addPersistentEntity(AbstractMappingContext.java:389)
at java.base/java.util.Collections$SingletonSet.forEach(Collections.java:4797)
at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext$PersistentPropertyCreator.createAndRegisterProperty(AbstractMappingContext.java:562)
at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext$PersistentPropertyCreator.doWith(AbstractMappingContext.java:520)
at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithFields(ReflectionUtils.java:705)
at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.addPersistentEntity(AbstractMappingContext.java:389)
at java.base/java.util.Collections$SingletonSet.forEach(Collections.java:4797)
at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext$PersistentPropertyCreator.createAndRegisterProperty(AbstractMappingContext.java:562)
at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext$PersistentPropertyCreator.doWith(AbstractMappingContext.java:520)
at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithFields(ReflectionUtils.java:705)
at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.addPersistentEntity(AbstractMappingContext.java:389)
at java.base/java.util.Collections$SingletonSet.forEach(Collections.java:4797)
at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext$PersistentPropertyCreator.createAndRegisterProperty(AbstractMappingContext.java:562)
at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext$PersistentPropertyCreator.doWith(AbstractMappingContext.java:520)
at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithFields(ReflectionUtils.java:705)
at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.addPersistentEntity(AbstractMappingContext.java:389)
at java.base/java.util.Collections$SingletonSet.forEach(Collections.java:4797)
at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext$PersistentPropertyCreator.createAndRegisterProperty(AbstractMappingContext.java:562)
at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext$PersistentPropertyCreator.doWith(AbstractMappingContext.java:520)
at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithFields(ReflectionUtils.java:705)
at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.addPersistentEntity(AbstractMappingContext.java:389)
at java.base/java.util.Collections$SingletonSet.forEach(Collections.java:4797)
at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext$PersistentPropertyCreator.createAndRegisterProperty(AbstractMappingContext.java:562)
at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext$PersistentPropertyCreator.doWith(AbstractMappingContext.java:520)
at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithFields(ReflectionUtils.java:705)
at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.addPersistentEntity(AbstractMappingContext.java:389)
at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.getPersistentEntity(AbstractMappingContext.java:263)
at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.getPersistentEntity(AbstractMappingContext.java:206)
at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.getPersistentEntity(AbstractMappingContext.java:90)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.lambda$afterPropertiesSet$4(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:295)
at java.base/java.util.Optional.ifPresent(Optional.java:183)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:295)
at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.support.ElasticsearchRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(ElasticsearchRepositoryFactoryBean.java:69)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1853)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1790)
... 62 common frames omitted
```

I tried with a more recent spring boot (2.4.4) and hibernate (5.4.29.Final) versions and got this stacktrace :

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'languageSearchRepository' defined in com.mycompany.myapp.repository.search.LanguageSearchRepository defined in @EnableElasticsearchRepositories declared on DatabaseConfiguration: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.StackOverflowError
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1786)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:602)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1380)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1300)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:887)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:791)
... 23 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.StackOverflowError: null
at org.springframework.data.util.ParameterizedTypeInformation.flattenTypeVariable(ParameterizedTypeInformation.java:303)
at org.springframework.data.util.ParameterizedTypeInformation.lambda$calculateTypeVariables$5(ParameterizedTypeInformation.java:283)
at java.base/java.util.stream.IntPipeline$1$1.accept(IntPipeline.java:180)
at java.base/java.util.stream.Streams$RangeIntSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:104)
at java.base/java.util.Spliterator$OfInt.forEachRemaining(Spliterator.java:699)
at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484)
at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:150)
at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:173)
at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:497)
at org.springframework.data.util.ParameterizedTypeInformation.calculateTypeVariables(ParameterizedTypeInformation.java:284)
at org.springframework.data.util.ParameterizedTypeInformation.<init>(ParameterizedTypeInformation.java:56)
at org.springframework.data.util.TypeDiscoverer.createInfo(TypeDiscoverer.java:124)
at org.springframework.data.util.ParentTypeAwareTypeInformation.createInfo(ParentTypeAwareTypeInformation.java:61)
at org.springframework.data.util.TypeDiscoverer.lambda$getPropertyInformation$1(TypeDiscoverer.java:227)
at java.base/java.util.Optional.map(Optional.java:265)
...
```

If I remove all ElasticSearchRepositories of my application, it works normally and @LazyToOne fields are well lazy loaded.

The error seems to come from  Spring Data’s Elasticsearch implementation...

Did you ever see anything like this ?

EDIT: As asked in comments, this is one of my elasticsearch Entity which is also an entity in my postgres database (powered by hibernate).

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "language")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
@Document(indexName = "language")
public class Language extends AbstractAuditingEntity implements 
Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

@NotNull
@Column(name = "name", nullable = false, unique = true)
private String name;

@NotNull
@Size(max = 10)
@Column(name = "code", length = 10, nullable = false, unique = true)
private String code;

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public Language name(String name) {
    this.name = name;
    return this;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getCode() {
    return code;
}

public Language code(String code) {
    this.code = code;
    return this;
}

public void setCode(String code) {
    this.code = code;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) {
        return true;
    }
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) {
        return false;
    }
    Language language = (Language) o;
    if (language.getId() == null || getId() == null) {
        return false;
    }
    return Objects.equals(getId(), language.getId());
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return Objects.hashCode(getId());
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Language{" +
            "id=" + getId() +
            ", name='" + getName() + "'" +
            ", code='" + getCode() + "'" +
            ", createdBy='" + getCreatedBy() + "'" +
            ", createdDate='" + getCreatedDate() + "'" +
            ", lastModifiedBy='" + getLastModifiedBy() + "'" +
            ", lastModifiedDate='" + getLastModifiedDate() + "'" +
            "}";
}
}
```

Comment: Please show the code for the entity class you are using in Spring Data Elasticsearch. Do you use these entity classes as well to be stored in some relational DB with hibernate?

Comment: Hey thanks for your comment. I edited my post with one of my entity class. Indeed, this entity is used by elasticsearch and also in my relational DB with hibernate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first error you're observing has been fixed in the more recent version, the one with the `getActualType()`. The other one I cannot nail down, but I think that the Hibernate bytecode manipulation destroys/removes information from the types of some properties that Spring Data needs - not only Spring Data Elasticsearch. I suppose you are not using a Spring Data module for the relation DB part as well.

Personally I never use the same entity for storing data in two different stores, or to store them and pass them out for example over a REST interface. That may convenient in the first place, but often leads to problems like the one here.

I'd suppose to use one entity to store the data in Spring Data Elasticsearch and a different one for the database maybe even a third for your daomain logic; you'll need mapper functions to map one into the other. That's more classes and more conversion, but if you then configure your hibernate setup to only process the DB entities and not the ones used for SDE, you will not have these problems.